# Find the coefficient using binomial theorem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

What is the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expression: $$(x+1)^{10}.(x^2 -1)^8$$

Comment: Hint : 20 = 4+16 = 6+14= 8+12 = 10+10

Comment: I tried simplification: this expression is equal to $$(x+1)^{18}.(x-1)^8$$
Then i can take the term $x^{18}$ of the first one and $x^2$ of the second. Then add the coeff of $x^{17}$ to the coeff of $x^3$ and so one. But i was trying to avoid this work...

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267846/please-solve-a-2013-th-derivative-question/267870#267870).

Answer (score 4):

$$(x+1)^{10}.(x^2 -1)^8=(x+1)^{18}.(x -1)^8=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{18} {18 \choose k} x^k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^8 {8 \choose \ell}x^\ell(-1)^{8-\ell}\right)$$ 
hence the coefficient of $x^{20}$ is
$$\sum_{k+\ell=20}(-1)^{\ell}{18 \choose k}{8 \choose \ell}$$

Answer (score 3):

From the binomial theorem you know that

$$(x+1)^{10}=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}kx^k$$

and

$$(x^2-1)^8=\sum_{k=0}^8\binom8k(-1)^{8-k}x^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^8\binom8k(-1)^kx^{2k}\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
(x+1)^{10}(x^2-1)^8&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^8\binom8k(-1)^kx^{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\left(1+10x+\ldots+10x^9+x^{10}\right)\left(1-8x^2+\ldots-8x^{14}+x^{16}\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

The $x^{20}$ term in the product will be the sum of all terms of the form $(ax^k)(bx^\ell)$ such that $k+\ell=20$. Find all of those combinations of $k$ and $\ell$, and you’re nearly there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate the work you had to write this formulas, but i get the idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @paimfp: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

$$(x+1)^{10}.(x^2 -1)^8=\sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{i}x^i\sum_{j=0}^{8}\binom{8}{j}x^{2j}(-1)^{8-j}$$

$$i+2j=20$$
$$(i,j)=(10,5),(8,6),(6,7),(4,8)$$

$$\binom{10}{10}\binom{8}{5}(-1)^{3}+\binom{10}{8}\binom{8}{6}(-1)^{2}+\binom{10}{6}\binom{8}{7}(-1)+\binom{10}{4}\binom{8}{8}(-1)^0=$$

$$=-\binom{8}{5}+\binom{10}{8}\binom{8}{6}-\binom{10}{6}\binom{8}{7}+\binom{10}{4}=-266$$

Comment: That's it, I did it and found $-266$ and that's correct. Thanks you all.