# Fourth degree Maclaurin $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{1-x}$$

I tried to differentiate it but it is very difficult, what is the trick?

Comment: You could find the terms up to order $4$ of the product of the series for $\sin x$ and $1/(1-x)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Why not make that an answer?

Comment: If you decide to make it an answer, @David, leave a comment on mine, and I'll delete it.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267846/please-solve-a-2013-th-derivative-question/267870#267870) for a related problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with David. Find the series for $\sin(x)$ and $\dfrac1{1-x}$ (a much simpler task), then find the first several terms of the product.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't follow what you are trying to say.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: the product of the series will give you the series of the product.

Comment: So I need to find the approximation for the sum and then multiply them?

Comment: @PaulthePirate $\sin x = x-x^3/3!+\cdots$ and $1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$. Just find the terms up to order $4$ of $( x-x^3/3!+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots  )$. Take care to note that in the product the "dots" give terms $c_k x^k$  with $k>4$, so you can ignore them.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: As tomasz points out, the product of the two Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ and $\dfrac1{1-x}$ will be precisely the Maclaurin series for $f(x)$. David has been gracious enough to narrow your parameters further, but you should be certain that you understand **why** you don't actually need the whole Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ or $\dfrac1{1-x},$ so that you can draw conclusions appropriately for future problems.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it somewhat the idea that $x^2 * x^2 = x^4$?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Note that all of the rest of the (non-zero) terms of the expansion of $\sin(x)$ are of degree *strictly higher* than $4$, so multiplication by any of the terms of the expansion of $\dfrac1{1-x}$ will again yield a term of degree strictly higher than $4$, which we don't need. Likewise, the rest of the terms of the expansion of $\dfrac1{1-x}$ are of degree *strictly higher* than $3$, so multiplication by any of the (nonzero) terms of the expansion of $\sin(x)$ will yield a term of degree strictly higher than $4$, which we don't need.