# Calculate $f^{(25)}(0)$ for $f(x)=x^2 \sin(x)$

Tags: calculus

Calculate $f^{(25)}(0)$ for $f(x)=x^2 \sin(x)$.

The answer is too short for me to understand, and the answer is

$- 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 8^{23}$

Comment: **HINT** Take the derivative 25 times, then plug in "0"

Comment: @DonLarynx : That would not be a better idea and i believe OP knows the definition of what it is written and what you have said is nothing more than a definition

Comment: What's the Maclaurin series for your function?

Comment: @DavidMitra : I do not quite understand your idea... you need that derivative to write maclaurian series right? I am missing something I guess...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You can find the Maclauren series of $f(x)=x^2\sin x$ by multiplying the Maclauren series for $\sin$ by $x^2$.

Comment: @DavidMitra : That would be very good if that is true (I do not know if you can get like that)... This is very nice thing to know... I would look into that in more detail... Thank you :)

Comment: Try using [General Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_rule_(generalized_product_rule))

Comment: MacLaurin series as David Mitra said, or [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) will also do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$f(x) = x^2\sin x$$
$$ = x^2 \left(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} +...- \frac{x^{23}}{23!} +...\right)$$
$$ = -\frac{x^{25}}{23!} +...$$
$$f^{(25)}(x) = -\frac{25!}{23!} + ...$$
$$f^{(25)}(0) = -600$$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25th+derivate+of+x%5E2sinx) verifies that the $8^{23}$ should not be there.

Answer (score 5):

use the leibnitz rule to find the  nth derivative of the function.
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(uv) = ^nC_0u \frac{d^n}{dx^n} (v)+^nC_1 \frac{d}{dx} (u) \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} v+...... ^nC_n \frac{d^n}{dx^n} (u)v$$
here $  u=x^2$ and $v=\sin x$
also note
$$ \frac{d^n}{dx^n} (\sin x)=sin(x+n\frac{\pi}{2})$$
on solving you get
$$f^{n}(x)=x^2\sin(x+n\frac{\pi}{2})+2nx\sin(x+(n-1)\frac{\pi}{2})+n(n-1)\sin (x+(n-2)\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Comment: wow, very fast downvote (not mine!)

Comment: i dont know why some are interested in downvoting without even noticing the idea behind the answer.

Comment: I upvote, and I really don't understand the downvote.

Comment: This seems to be a very good answer as it does not use the Taylor's theorem which is probably at a higher level than Leibniz rule for differentiation. I wonder why it is becoming common to down-vote without giving even a few words of comment.

Answer (score 3):

The answer you have stated is wrong. It should be $-25*24$. Note that in the Taylor expansion for $f(x)$ the only non-zero term that matters is $-x^{25}/23!$.  Differentiate this last expression $25$ terms and plug in zero, you will get

$$f^{(25)}(0) = -25!/23! = -600.$$

Comment: I think it is $\frac{-x^{25}}{25!}$.

Comment: Ok get it ! There's another $x^2$ to be multiplied with !

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach. Follow the steps

i) use the identity $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix} }{2i} $

ii) use the product rule for differentition.

Note that the function $(x^2)^{(m) }$ vanishes for $m=3$.  Chech this [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267846/please-solve-a-2013-th-derivative-question/267870#267870).