# Proving $(e^x\sin x)^{(n)}=2^{\frac n2}e^x \sin (x+n\cdot\frac{\pi}4) $

Tags: calculus

> Prove :$$(e^x\sin x)^{(n)}=2^{\frac n2}e^x \sin (x+n\cdot\frac{\pi}4) \\ \forall x\in\mathbb R, \ n\ge1$$
>
> Hint: Use the trig identity $\sin(a+b)$

Well the trig identity is equal to $\sin a \cos b +\cos a \ sin b$.

I tried to find a pattern as I derived, it goes like this:

$(e^x\sin x)^{(n)}=\\\begin{align}&(n=1)  &(e^x\sin x+e^x\cos x)=A \\
& (n=2)&  (A+(e^x\cos x -e^x\sin x)=B)\\
&(n=3)&A+B+B-A=2B\\
&(n=4)&...=-4A\\
&(n=5)&-4(A+B)  \end{align}$

It seems periodic but I just don't see the rule that will make the two sides equal...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taylor series for $e^z\sin(z)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622215/taylor-series-for-ez-sinz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\sin x +\cos x =\sqrt2(\sin x \cos\frac\pi4+\cos x\sin\frac\pi4)$ starting in step $n=1$.

Comment: Which is equal to the RHS only with n=1. I assume I need to continue with induction ?

Comment: Yes of course. The next derivative contains $\sin(x+\frac π4)+\cos(x+\frac π4)$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

to find the $nth$ derivative of 
$$e^{az}\sin (bz+c)$$
differentiating this expression once
$$D^1=e^{az}(a\sin (bz+c)+b\cos (bz+c))$$
let $a=r\cos \theta$ and $b=r\sin \theta$. you get
$$D^1= e^{az}r\sin (bz+c+\theta)$$
if you observe you see
$$D^n= e^{az}r^n\sin (bz+c+n\theta)$$
where $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$  and $\theta=\arctan(\frac{b}{a})$
now substitute for $a,b,c$.

Comment: Why is there an a in exponenet of e ?

Comment: Also, this doesn't get you $2^{\frac n2}$...

Comment: Yeah I noticed it's a very general solution. About the arctan,  $atan \frac12\neq\frac\pi4$ (after checking in my calculator) also those $a,b$ won't give you $\sqrt{2}$ but $\sqrt{5}$ Also, Is this some useful/known identity ?

Comment: @GinKin Suraj is incorrect, your case is $a=b=1,c=0$, which means his answer disagrees with you by a factor of $2^{n/2}$.